# Inertia matrix of a rod rotating about an axis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

I'll provide a picture for clearer understanding. The problem is to calculate the angular momentum of the rod rotating about the z-axis. I have serious difficulties in deriving the inertia matrix, that's all I need help with.

[image]

**Progress**

Since the rod is rotating about the z-axis $\Rightarrow \omega _{x}=\omega _{y}=0$ the angular momentum simplifies to

$ \boldsymbol{L}_{O}=-I_{xz}\omega _{z}\hat{\mathbf{i}}-I_{yz}\omega _{z}\boldsymbol{\hat{j}}+I_{zz}\omega_{z}\boldsymbol{\hat{k}} $

Split the rod in three parts (SEE FIGURE) and calculate for each body.

I have correct terms for body **A**.

For **B**:

$I_{xz}=\overline{I}_{xz}+md_{x}d_{z} = 0 +\rho b(0)(\frac{b}{2})=0$
$I_{yz}=\overline{I}_{yz}+md_{y}d_{z} = 0 +\rho b(b)(\frac{b}{2})=\frac{1}{2}\rho b^3$ 
**Wrong**

$I_{zz}=\overline{I}_{zz}+md^2 = 0 + (\rho b)(b^2+(\frac{b}{2})^2)=\frac{5}{4}\rho b^3$ (d is distance from midpoint of [B]B[/B] to origin O)

For **C**:

$I_{xz}=\overline{I}_{xz}+md_{x}d_{z} = 0 +\rho b(\frac{b}{2})(b)=\frac{1}{2}\rho b^3$
$I_{yz}=\overline{I}_{yz}+md_{y}d_{z} = 0 +\rho b(b)(b)=\rho b^3$

**Wrong**$I_{zz}=\overline{I}_{zz}+md^2 = \frac{1}{3}(\rho b)(b^2)+(\rho b)((2b^2)^2+(\frac{b}{2})^2)=\frac{55}{12}\rho b^3$ (distance d is from midpoint of [B]C[/B] to origin O)

Comment: You appear to have neglected to account for the fact that the radial distance from origin to each location on the C-leg varies as a sine function, but maybe that's embedded in one of your (unattributed) formulas?

Comment: No, actually I was thinking of using coordinate axis that rotates with the body. Does that make sense?

Comment: Maybe, **B** is just too simple;-). Note, that all mass of rod **B** is concentrated at the same distance to the axis of rotation. **C** is almost the same as **A**. You just have to add the Steiner part.

Comment: @EricAm: It's not necessary to compute the moment of inertia of the three segments separately. A far easier way is to just use the parallel axis theorem and the inertia tensor of a rod.

Comment: Ok, I solved it. Can I answer my own question?

Comment: @EricAm: Yup, that's fine, you can even accept your answer if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternate answer using parallel axis theorem, note that the inertia tensor of a rod pointing in the $y$-direction rotating about its center is 
$$\mathbf{I}_\text{rod,y}=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{b^3 \rho }{12} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{b^3 \rho }{12} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
and similar for the $x$ and $z$-pointing rods, so the unshifted inertia tensor for the whole system becomes $\mathbf{I}_c=\mathbf{I}_\text{rod,x}+\mathbf{I}_\text{rod,y}+\mathbf{I}_\text{rod,z}=\frac{1}{6}\rho b^3\mathbf{E}$ where $\mathbf{E}$ is the identity matrix. Meanwhile the translation component is $$\mathbf{I}_t=\sum_{j=1}^3b\rho((\mathbf{R}_j\cdot\mathbf{R}_j)\mathbf{E}-\mathbf{R}_j\otimes\mathbf{R}_j)$$
where $\mathbf{R}_j$ are the centers of the rods, giving the inertia tensor
$$\mathbf{I}=\mathbf{I}_c+\mathbf{I}_t=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{11 b^3 \rho }{3} & -\frac{b^3 \rho }{2} & -\frac{b^3 \rho }{2} \\
 -\frac{b^3 \rho }{2} & \frac{5 b^3 \rho }{3} & -\frac{3 b^3 \rho }{2} \\
 -\frac{b^3 \rho }{2} & -\frac{3 b^3 \rho }{2} & \frac{8 b^3 \rho }{3} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
which was obtained using the following code:

```
i = IdentityMatrix[3];
f[R_] := b \[Rho] ((R.R) i - R\[TensorProduct]R);
{R1, R2, R3} = {{0, b/2, 0}, {0, b, b/2}, {b/2, b, b}};
MatrixForm[b^3 \[Rho]/6 i + f[R1] + f[R2] + f[R3]] // TeXForm
```

From this, the angular momentum and energy can be computed via $\mathbf{L}=\mathbf{I}\boldsymbol{\omega}$ and $T=\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{\omega}\mathbf{I}\boldsymbol{\omega}$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question. Since $\boldsymbol{\omega }=\omega _{z}\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}$ the angular momentum reduces to

$ \boldsymbol{L}_{O}=-I_{xz}\omega _{z}\hat{\mathbf{i}}-I_{yz}\omega _{z}\boldsymbol{\hat{j}}+I_{zz}\omega_{z}\boldsymbol{\hat{k}}$. We can split the rod in three pieces, calculate moment(product of inertia for each body and sum up.

For **A**:

$I_{xz}=I_{yz}=0$ and $I_{zz}=\frac{1}{3}\rho b^3$.

For **B**:

$I_{xz}=\overline{I}_{xz}+md_{x}d_{y}=0+\rho b(0)(\frac{b}{2})=0$

$I_{yz}=\overline{I}_{yz}+md_{y}d_{z}=0+\rho b(b)(\frac{b}{2})=\frac{1}{2}\rho b^3$

$I_{zz}=\overline{I}_{zz}+md^2=0+\rho b(b^2)=\rho b^3$

For **C**:

$I_{xz}=\overline{I}_{xz}+md_{x}d_{z}=0+\rho b(\frac{b}{2})(b)=\frac{1}{2}\rho b^3$

$I_{yz}=\overline{I}_{yz}+md_{y}d_{z}=0+\rho b(b)(b)=\rho b^3$

$I_{zz}=\overline{I}_{zz}+md^2 = \frac{1}{3}\rho b(b^2)+m(b^2)=\frac{4}{3}\rho b^3  $

Sum these up and plug in to the angular momentum equation above yields:

$\boldsymbol{L_{O}}=\rho b^3\omega (-\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{\hat{i}}-\frac{3}{2}\boldsymbol{\hat{j}}+\frac{8}{3}\boldsymbol{\hat{k}})$

For the kinetic energy we can perform the dot product and achieve $T=\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{\omega }\cdot \boldsymbol{L_{O}}=\frac{4}{3}\rho b^3 \omega^2$